# Can parameters in MessageFormat strings be optional?

Tags: php, internationalization, icu, messageformat

I am using the [MessageFormatter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.messageformatter.php) class to format translated strings to display to the end user.

The catch is that I also need to insert some html markup into the final result. For example, the string might just be `Peter liked a photo`, however, I need the final result to contain markup:

```
<a href="blah.com">Peter</a> liked <a href="blah2.com">a photo</a>
```

After doing lots of research, in particular, these questions

- [How do you handle translation of text with markup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273847/how-do-you-handle-translation-of-text-with-markup)
- [Good method to do text with links in gettext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484941/good-method-to-do-text-with-links-in-gettext)

I decided to use this approach:

```
{1}{0}{2} liked {3}a photo{4}
```

Where:

```
{0} = Peter
{1} = <a href="blah.com">
{2} = </a>
{3} = <a href="blah2.com">
{4} = </a>
```

This has worked pretty well, besides being a bit cumbersome. However, the main reason I didn't want to include the markup into resource bundle strings was because, sometimes, I want the strings returned without the HTML tags.

The issue is that if I just pass 1 parameter (Peter) to `MessageFormatter`, it complains that I have missing parameters.

One work around I could do is to pass this (`{1}` to `{5}` would be empty strings):

```
{0} = Peter
{1} = 
{2} = 
{3} = 
{4} =
```

However, this is extremely cumbersome and not very nice.

Is there anyway I can mark a parameter as optional (essentially, to just ignore the parameter, if a value for it is not passed in) in a message format string?

Comment: Another option may be to use ICU's choice selector's in the format to return a plain-text formatted string or a HTML/mark up string. In any case AFAIK if you supply {n} you'd better pass in something for n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP 5.5 this is now possible as stated in the [changed functions guide](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration55.changed-functions.php).

> MessageFormatter::format() and related functions no longer error when
> an insufficient number of arguments have been provided. Instead, the
> placeholders will not be substituted.